# Is there any possibility to create uneven horizontal progress bar in android studio?

Tags: android, kotlin, progress-bar

Is there any possibility to create uneven horizontal progress bar in android studio?

I want to create the following progress bar, how can i do this?

[image]

I didn't find any information regarding how i can create uneven shape.